# Method name in soap message request

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I have an interesting problem, I'm using SOAP UI to parse the WSDL. The WSDL from payPal

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/
```

When I try to load it in SOAP UI, all the method names are getting created that's fine, but when I look into the Messages, The method name in tree view is `BillOutstandingAmount` But when I open the request

```
 <soapenv:Body>
  <urn:BillOutstandingAmountReq>
   ....
  </urn:BillOutstandingAmountReq>
</soapenv:Body>
```

How the method name in SOAP request can be changed.? Is there any annotation to do so? When I look into the WSDL,

```
<wsdl:message name="BillOutstandingAmountRequest">
 <wsdl:part name="BillOutstandingAmountRequest" element="ns:BillOutstandingAmountReq"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

The operation part of WSDL

```
<wsdl:operation name="BillOutstandingAmount">
 <wsdl:input message="ns:BillOutstandingAmountRequest"/>
 <wsdl:output message="ns:BillOutstandingAmountResponse"/>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours I found the answer

```
@RequestWrapper(localName="localRequestName")
```

Whatever we're giving in the annotation localName will be the SOAP Request method name.